# Problema con una variable en php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Estoy tratando de hacer una acción de edición con este código de php:

```
<?php 

    include 'includes/connect.php';


    if(isset($_POST['hidden_id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
        $edit_post_query = "SELECT * FROM index_posts WHERE id =".$id;
        $edit_post_result = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_post_query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($edit_post_result) == 1) {
            $edit_post_row = mysqli_fetch_array($edit_post_result);
            $hidden_id = $edit_post_row['hidden_id'];
            $edit_post_title = $edit_post_row['post_title'];
            $edit_post_text = $edit_post_row['post_text'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Pero tengo un error que me dice que las variables no son identificadas, al parecer esto es porque el método mysqli_num_rows no esta recibiendo ninguna fila de la base de datos, ya revisé el nombre de las columnas y si son correctos, traté de concatenar la variable del id a la consulta.

Este es mi formulario de HTML

```
<form action="past_entries.php" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo                                     
    $_GET['hidden_id'];?>">
    <input class="new-record-input" type="text" name="post_title"     
     value="<?php echo $edit_post_title['post_title']; ?>" style="border-    
     radius: 5px;width:100%;margin:5px auto;">
     <textarea class="edit-index-text" name="post_text" style="border-radius:5px;"> <?php echo $edit_post_text['post_text']; ?> </textarea> 
    <a href="edit_past_entry.php?id=<?php echo $past_entry_row['id'];?>"> <button class="save-post-btn">Guardar</button> </a>
</form>
```

También trate de asignarles un valor de null y  de 1 pero tampoco parece que funciona de esa manera

Comment: puedo ver su valor si aplico la variable de row que se encuenra dentro del SELECT, uso $past_entry_row despues de haber echo esto, esto aparece:  Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/directory/past_entries.php on line 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código no debería ser *mudo* en muchos aspectos. Hay al menos 4 posibles escenarios que no están cubiertos en él y deberías cubrirlos, emitiendo mensajes adecuados o cualquier otra cosa.

Pensando la programación como algo estrictamente controlado, todavía se puede apreciar un error de lógica. ¿Qué debería ocurrir cuando no se encuentran datos? El código que pide los datos debe recibir algún indicador de que no hay dato (un booleano u otra cosa) para saber lo que hay que hacer.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de código controlado, puedes implementar fácilmente lo que te decía al final del último párrafo, según el contexto que pide los datos y lo que haya que hacer en consecuencia.

```
<?php 
    $id=!empty($_POST['hidden_id']) ? $_POST['hidden_id'] : NULL;
    if ($id) 
    {
        include 'includes/connect.php';
        if ($conn) 
        {
            $edit_post_query = "SELECT * FROM index_posts WHERE id = $id";
            if ($edit_post_result = mysqli_query($conn, $edit_post_query) ) 
            {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($edit_post_result) > 0) 
                {
                    $edit_post_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($edit_post_result);
                    $hidden_id = $edit_post_row['hidden_id'];
                    $edit_post_title = $edit_post_row['post_title'];
                    $edit_post_text = $edit_post_row['post_text'];
                } else {
                    echo "No se encontraron filas";
                }
            } else { 
                echo "Error en la consulta: {mysqli_error($conn)}";
            }
        } else {
            echo "No hay conexión";
        }
    } else {
        echo "No se envío dato para el id, revise el formulario";
    }    
?>
```